# How to amimate bristles vibrating on water surface?

Tags: rendering, particles, fluid-simulation, geometry, shape-keys

I'm trying to recreate this kind of animation (reference video below) but I'm wondering the best way to animate the water at the bottom and the water drops. It could be, particles, fluid simulation, geometry nodes(?), or even shape keys. Focusing on that I need it to be "real".

You can see the reference in this youtube link:

[image: preview reference animation]

- https://youtu.be/mlTCZDiB_VQ

What do you think is a better way to animate this ? Some tutorial links could help a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a particle system for the droplets. For the water you could use a *Displace* modifier with a *Cloud* texture controlled by an empty that moves on Z, and a vertex group to keep the displacement where you want. For the whole water give it a material with *Transmission* at 1, and with a *Noise Texture* as bump that also moves on Z:

[image]

You can create a plane that will have *Collision* and enable its *Kill Particles* option so that all these particles don't go through its surface. Under the surface you can create another particle system for the bubbles, with bigger particles:

[image]